# How much can the density of a continuous measure be zero?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Assume you have a (Borel) probability measure $\mu$ on $[0,1]$ with full support, $\mathrm{supp}(\mu)=[0,1]$, which is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue, i.e. there exists a measurable map $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ such that $d\mu=f\, dx$.

Is is true that the set $\{f=0\}$ has zero Lebesgue measure?

It seems to be true but I don't manage to prove it. Somehow the question's spirit is "what can you say on the support $\{f\neq 0\}$ of $f$ from the support of $\mu$?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is well known that there exists a measurable set $E$ in $(0,1)$ such that $0<m(E\cap I)<m(I)$ for every open interval $I$. If $\mu(A)=m(A\cap E)$ then $\mu (I) =m(I\cap E)>0$ for every open interval $I$ so $\mu$ has full support. But $\frac {d\mu} {dm} =I_E$ which vanishes on $E^{c}$ and $m(E^{c}) >0$ because $m(E\cap (0,1))<m((0,1))=1$.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any reference concerning the existence of such a set $E$?

Comment: It is an exercise in Rudin's RCA. You have to construct a Cantor set of positive measure; then construct such a set in each of the intervals removed and keep repeating this process. The union of all these cantor sets has the required properties. @Student

Comment: Thank you very much! The fat Cantor sets struck again...

Comment: Did I understand your argument correctly?: it says that it is possible for a measure absolutely continuous w.r.t. Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$ and with full support to have a density w.r.t. Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$ that is vanishing on a set of posivitve (Lebesgue) measure. Thanks!

Comment: @MrFranzén You are right. Even though the density cannot vanish on any open interval it can vanish on a set of positive measure.